# Best way to transfer data between SQL Servers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, data-transfer

I have a general in-office database and a bunch of laptop-installed SQL Server Express databases of the same structure. In these databases I log information, which is partitioned by the id of a specific event. The laptops are taken by employees mostly to service one event (2-3 at the most sometimes), and obviously I have an `eventId` column in all tables except the dictionaries in the databases (though it rarely goes above 3 on the laptop databases).

When the employees come back to the office, they need to backup the last event data to the office SQL Server, where `eventId`'s can be a hundred or a thousand, etc., this is the history of all past events.

Another reason for my question is I would like to be able to make an `eventId`-based selective copy of an existing database to a different server for development purposes (from local to SQL Azure actually).

What is the efficient way of moving such data between servers? I have approximately 50-100 tables with keys and references.

1. What we do at the moment - selective copying the data to a new clean database on source server (only whatever is required for copying); backing up this new DB; restoring it on a target server; data copy between databases using dynamic T-SQL with a dbname as a parameter. What I don't like is dynamic T-Sql, no syntax check at all until runtime.
2. Loading data somewhat in RAM with help of developing a C# program (but it may be too resource consuming, as long as data may be large) and transferring it to a new server with a C# program as a proxy and RAM as intermediate storage. Challenging and in certain situations impossible (too much data).
3. I started looking into SSIS, but it seems that the general advice for use of SSIS is when copying is done at fixed environment ("in-house"). We supply software not to a vast amount of customers, but there surely are more than one, and we would need to pass connection information dynamically from somewhere, as long as we can't visit all our customers to prepare a set-up for them on location.
4. Any other suggestions?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would recommend.

Create an SSIS package. Install it on the Laptops SQL Server Express.

You can use a configuration file that will allow you to select which Event Ids you want to Export.

You can also keep all of your connection information in the configuration file. For those non in-house customers you can remove the configuration file between exports.

That would be my recommendation.

Comment: Would that allow a non-programmer to use it? I.e. open a window, select source, select target, authenticate for both and do the transfer?

Comment: I would create a JOB for the SSIS package. Let the SSIS package do all of the authenticating. I wouldn't open a window, just run the job, and let it do what it does. You could even schedule it to do it nightly, so that no user intervention would be required.

Comment: AFAIK, jobs should occur on regular intervals, being regular scheduled events. The users need more freedom and more control over what's happening. I'm a developer of software which leaves the company, not the server administrator, who may play with his server. And the users have little knowledge of server administration, they need user-friendly interface for their tasks.

Comment: A job can be scheduled, run on command, or both. If you like, you can create a script file that they can click, and it will start the job.